# Percona xtradb cluster node crash

Tags: mysql, percona, galera

I have a PXC with three nodes. But when one of the node crashed, the other nodes followed suit.

What does the first paragraph (Trying to get some variables...) of the error below mean? In what circumstance does this error or message happen?

```
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f7bf80f5c30): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 323203618
Status: NOT_KILLED

You may download the Percona XtraDB Cluster operations manual by visiting
http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtradb-cluster/. You may find information
in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
150809 05:13:51 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
150809 05:13:51 mysqld_safe WSREP: not restarting wsrep node automatically
150809 05:13:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/db-3-2.pid ended
```

Comment: Did all the nodes crash with similar output? What version of PXC and Galera are you running?  Isn't there a little bit more output above here?  Something about "caught signal..." or "we intentionally generate..."

Comment: I am running version 5.6.25-73 for PXC, and Galera version 3.12. This is the only part of the output which contain errors. The rest is just normal logging. And all logs also reported this part of the log.